# C#, entity framework and user permissions, how to do it in a WPF application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, permissions

I have a main WPF application which uses a repository to access to the database. This repository have all the actions that can be done, however some users should not do some operations: add, deleted, etc.

I would like to know which is the best way to do that. Do I need to implement this in the main application, disabling buttons and checking if the user has permission or is a best option to control this in the repository? if I do it in the repository, perhaps I need always an extra query to the database to check if the user has permission, and I always need to pass as parameter the user and password.

Some other alternative?

Comment: I think what you need are role for users and permissions.